# How to search docx for a specific string and return the outline number

Tags: c#, search, docx

I am using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExtractTextFromDOCXs.aspx?msg=3290333#xx3290333xx) as a starting base. I can search the document but am unable to reference what section it is from, is there something built into the OpenXML API to do this?

For example lets say the the document is 500 pages and it is in a standard numbering schema

1.

1.1

1.1.1

1.1.1.1     searchWord

1.1.1.2

23.1.2.3.4.  searchWord

I would like to search by search word and return it's section 1.1.1.1 & 23.1.2.3.4

Regards

_Eric

Comment: did you have any luck with this Eric, I'm now attempting the same thing and was wondering if you had an update you could offer.

Comment: @Jake, I don't think so that was a while ago and I don't remember the alternate solution I used